# How to check internet connection in react native?

Tags: react-native

I want to check the internet connectivity when starting the app, then ask the user to connect to the internet if he doesn't

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate. Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57296756/how-to-check-internet-connection-in-react-native-application-for-both-ios-and-an

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
import NetInfo from '@react-native-community/netinfo';

NetInfo.fetch().then((state) => {
    console.log('Connection type', state.type);
    console.log('Is connected?', state.isConnected);
});

const unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener((state) => {
    console.log('Connection type', state.type);
    console.log('Is connected?', state.isConnected);
});
```

Answer (score 9):

You should use the "@react-native-community/netinfo" library. NetInfo used to be part of the react-native, but then it got separated out of the core. If you want to observe network state changes just use the provided addEventListener method.

```
import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo";

NetInfo.fetch().then(state => {
    console.log("Connection type", state.type);
    console.log("Is connected?", state.isConnected);
});

const unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
    console.log("Connection type", state.type);
    console.log("Is connected?", state.isConnected);
});

// Unsubscribe
unsubscribe();
```

Comment: nice answer twboc

Answer (score 0):

For my project I've used **NetInfo**, according to state of connection I'm toggling No Internet screen

```js
  useEffect(() => {

    NetInfo.fetch().then((state) => {

    console.log('Is connected?', state.isConnected);

    setShowNoInterNetPage(!state?.isConnected)

   });

  const unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener((state) => {

      console.log('Is connected?', state.isConnected);

  });

    return () => unsubscribe;
    
  }, [])
```

Comment: You can take a look here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77029163/react-native-check-if-there-is-internet-connection-via-listener