# React native check if there is internet connection via listener

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, react-native-community-netinfo

In your opinion this is the right approach:

```js
  const [isNetwork, setIsNetwork] = useState(true);
  const [isChangeNetwork, setIsChangeNetwork] = useState(false);



useEffect(() => {
    NetInfo.fetch().then(({ isConnected, isInternetReachable }) =>
      setIsNetwork(isConnected && isInternetReachable)
    );
    const unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener(
      ({ isConnected, isInternetReachable }) => {
        setIsNetwork(isConnected && isInternetReachable);
        setIsChangeNetwork(true);
      });
    return () => unsubscribe.remove();
  }, []);


...

 <Snackbar
          visible={isChangeNetwork}
          onDismiss={() => setIsChangeNetwork(false)}
          duration={3000}
          theme={{ colors: { inverseSurface: isNetwork ? 'green' : 'red' } }}>
          {isNetwork ? "Internet" : "No Internet"}
        </Snackbar>
```

First I get the error: here: `return () => unsubscribe.remove();`
Visual studio also tells me:

```
Property 'remove' does not exist in type 'NetInfoSubscription'.ts(2339)
```

[image]

Can you suggest me a better method?

One problem is that when starting the app, even if there is internet, the Snackbar appears and says there is internet.

Instead I want the Snackbar to appear only in these cases:

1. It is not there when starting the app
2. There is a change of state, like here for example:

a) First there is internet (then nothing appears), then there is no internet (then the Snackbar appears)

b) First there is no internet (then the Snackbar appears), then there is the internet (then the Snackbar appears)

Can you give me a hand?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is correct, the only thing is to use `unsubscribe();`
instead `unsubscribe.remove();`

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener(
      ({ isInternetReachable }) => {
        if(isNetwork != isInternetReachable) {
          setIsNetwork(isInternetReachable);
          setIsChangeNetwork(true);
        }
      });
    return () => unsubscribe();
}, []);
```

Comment: finally got there too, the problem that listener is called too many times.

See this example: https://snack.expo.dev/e0-ElvANW

Comment: You can not want the message to appear when starting the app if there is internet.

Comment: It doesn't even work, same situation.
At the beginning always appears the writing there is internet, if there is one.
Listener is called too many times.

Comment: Could you please try again with the updated code which includes condition for unnecessary state update.
If still issue persist, may be some issue with your package version or device (change device and check) where NetInfo listens without any change in network.

Comment: Case:
When the connection does not exist and then it is activated, the message that there is a connection is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

For my project I made custom hook of netInfo, it works fine for me you can try  using below code with your snackBar,

`useNetInfo.js ::::::Custom Hook`

```js
import NetInfo from '@react-native-community/netinfo';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { blue } from 'console-log-colors';

const useNetInfo = () => {
  
  const [connectionInfo, setConnectionInfo] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {

    NetInfo.fetch().then(state => {
      console.log(blue(':::-> Is Internet connected '), state.isConnected);
      setConnectionInfo(state.isConnected);
    });

   let netInfoListener = NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
      console.log(blue(':::-> Internet connection sate '), state.isConnected);
      setConnectionInfo(state.isConnected);
    });

    return () => netInfoListener  //<- Try this Instead of netInfoListener.remove();


  }, [connectionInfo]);

  return [connectionInfo];
};

export default useNetInfo;
```

`App.js`

```js
const App = () => {

  const [connectionInfo] = useNetInfo(); //<- Here's how I've used netInfo customHook

  console.log(connectionInfo)

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Main />
        </NavigationContainer>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```