# Can react-native app know when the phone have no service?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Instead letting user read the status bar, is a programmatic way to detect the "no service" state?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check internet connection in React Native application for both iOS and Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57296756/how-to-check-internet-connection-in-react-native-application-for-both-ios-and-an)

Comment: Apple advises against preflight checks or trying to track the connection state. The network can go away at any instant and can come back at any instant. Better to just try and handle errors.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `NetInfo` package for this, at first import that :

```
import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo";
```

You can subscribe to network state changes using the `addEventListener()` method:

```
NetInfo.addEventListener(networkState => {
  console.log("Connection type - ", networkState.type);
  console.log("Is connected? - ", networkState.isConnected);
});
```

for more info see [Link](https://blog.logrocket.com/managing-network-connection-status-in-react-native/)